# i have trouble with TessBaseAPI()

Tags: python, image-processing, python-tesseract

With code:

```
import tesseract

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
```

I have an error:

```
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'
```

used **sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr**

Comment: what is your file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the right import isn't `import pytesseract` ?

If it's `import tesseract`, did you installed the latest version of it and did you used **pip** ?

Maybe this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr) could help you.

Did you try this :

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI

images = ['sample.jpg', 'sample2.jpg', 'sample3.jpg']

with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    for img in images:
        api.SetImageFile(img)
        print api.GetUTF8Text()
        print api.AllWordConfidences()
```

Comment: tried all possible ways but i don't understand what is happening

Comment: Try to uninstall it and to install it properly following the link

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I needed to install the C++ tesseract library (not just the python wrapper) and provide a path to it when initializing the tesserocr API:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
api = PyTessBaseAPI(lang='eng', path=r'C:\python\envs\python36\Lib\site-packages\tesserocr\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata')
```

For windows 7, I got a windows installer, like this:
https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_tesseract-ocr-alt/downloads/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe/

Note that there is a version 4.0, so you should google for the latest version.

Also - the path is specifically to the `tessdata` folder that is created from the library.